# Can a subview of a custom cell go outside it's bounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tableView where, on selection the cell increases in width like as if we are pulling out a drawer from shelf.

Is it possible for me to have a subview inside the cell and increase it's width on selection of the cell ?

Comment: yes it is possible...

Comment: Sure it can. What's the matter?

Comment: I like the example, **"like as if we are pulling out a drawer from shelf."** :D

Comment: I was actually putting an overlay on the tableview exactly where the cell starts.
So I was about to move all this logic inside the custom cell instead of putting it inside the view controller.
So I wanted to be sure instead of being brave.

Comment: UI/UX Designers throw all sorts of challenges at you for simple things.
:P

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. In `tableViewDidSelectRow` method you get `indexPath` of `cell` selected. From that you get cell and change its views frame accordingly.